# Can I use two col-md-6 inside a col-md-8?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Can I use two col-md-6 inside a col-md-8 or must I use two col-md-4?

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-6">
        </div> 
    </div>

 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
 </div> 
</div>
```

Can I consider a col-md-8 as a col-md-12 if I insert a `<div class="row">` inside the col-md-8?

I tried it and it offers me the required result, but **is it proper**?

Comment: Yes. It should work as you have it. Why are you asking?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how it's support to be :) Enjoy :)

Comment: Yes because col-md-6 has width: 50%, but maybe insted on row use col-md-12 and so the html will be more clear. That depends on your style

Comment: @isherwood I wasn't sure if I had to use two col-md-4 instead (4+4 = col-md-8)

Comment: Looking at the applied CSS gives clues. The `.col-md-6` class applies a 50% width.

Comment: REPHRASE IN CAPS... IN A BS ROW, THERE'S ALWAYS 12 COLS.. No matter where the row is, who cares...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting):

> To nest your content with the default grid, add a new `.row` and set of
> `.col-sm-*` columns within an existing `.col-sm-*` column. Nested rows
> should include a set of columns that add up to 12 or fewer (it is not
> required that you use all 12 available columns).

So, yes you can.